# nginx error - nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:21

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, syntax, digital-ocean

I have just edited a server block file on my ubuntu server, and nginx won't start. When I try to debug the sites-available file, it gives me the error above. I can't work out what's wrong with line 21. The file looks like so:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /srv/www/macpherson;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    #server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    root /srv/www/macpherson;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name macphersoncpa.ca www.macphersoncpa.ca; # managed by Certbot


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/macphersoncpa.ca/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/macphersoncpa.ca/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Can anyone please help me fix this? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. I suspect that there is an error in a previous file that causes the `server` directive to appear in the wrong context.

Comment: How is this file included/used?